# Get group percentages in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am constructing a network graph where I would like the weight of the edges to be the percentage of outputs that follows some specific edge. Given the following example:

```
import pandas as pd
dff = pd.DataFrame()
dff['source'] = ['a','a','a','b','b','b','b']
dff['target'] = ['b','c','b','d','d','e','d']
```

I would like to get back something like this:

```
a       b         66%
        c         34%
b       d         75%
        e         25%
```

What I have so far is only able to group and sum, not sure how to make this into percentages?

```
dff.groupby(['source', 'target']).size()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. Use `groupby` + `count` -

```
v = df.groupby(['source', 'target']).source.count()
```

You could also use `size`, but note that `size` *also* counts `NaN` entries (`count` does not) -

```
v = df.groupby(['source', 'target']).size()
```

Now, find the sum along the 0<sup>th</sup> index level, and divide the original amount by this sum -

```
v / v.sum(level=0) * 100

source  target
a       b         66.666667
        c         33.333333
b       d         75.000000
        e         25.000000
Name: source, dtype: float64
```

If you want the `%` symbol on the right of the percentages, convert to string -

```
(v / v.sum(level=0) * 100).round(2).astype(str) + '%'

source  target
a       b         66.67%
        c         33.33%
b       d          75.0%
        e          25.0%
Name: source, dtype: object
```